# How to hash or encrypt user IDs in URL

Tags: html, http, url, encryption

I am developing an app and I would need at some point to encrypt the user credentials I am sending in URL as far as it is just a plain text now which is not secure at all.

The example of a code I would need to encrypt is as follows:

```
<a type="button" href="http://<%= host %>/play?user=<%= users.id %>" class="btn btn-primary">Create new scene</a>
```

I found `encodeURIComponent(str);` function and also a `sessions` would be another possibility? But I am not really sure how to implement this to my code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you intend to decrypt this information? If you're going to do it on the client side, then there probably isn't much point in encrypting this information in the first place because it will always be accessible to the client. If you're decrypting in the server, then why do you need to include all this extra markup? Can't you just encrypt `users.id` and `host`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you should do two steps:

1. Instead of credentials you should employ a server-generated token using a
   secret, e.g. `<userId, timestamp, hmac(userId + timestamp + secret)>` in response to an authentication by the user (e.g. OAuth, HTTP Basic or a custom API). This allows authorization without sending a password that can be read by an attacker. A solid implementation of this scheme is [JSON Web Tokens](https://jwt.io/) that are available in many programming languages.
2. If you use the token in the URL, be aware that if users copy and share the links, the access rights will be delegated. Therefore the expiration using the timestamp should not be too high. In order to circumvent this problem, you can also use cookies instead. In that case, your server replies with a `set-cookie: token` and the browser will automatically attach the cookie in each request to the same domain.

Be sure to use SSL, so a man-in-the-middle cannot sniff the credentials or tokens.